# Invalid escape sequence \\ is used but it still doesnt work in java for my file path

Tags: java, eclipse

I have read the other posts and answers and applied them but it still doesnt work.

I am brand new to Java in my class but it's online and accelerated so it's a bit difficult for me to understand at a quick pace so please bear with me if i don't understand.

```
String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Jonathan Lee\\eclipse-workspace\myfile.text";
```

I have that and I've tried different amount of backslashes but that seems to create even more errors.

Comment: have you tried `fileName = "C:/Users/Jonathan Lee/eclipse-workspace/myfile.text";`

Comment: try String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Jonathan Lee\\eclipse-workspace\\myfile.text";

Comment: impossible to learn java (programming language) without book, longer consistent course etc.

Comment: Hard to belive You really try (two backslashes is too hard to try)

Comment: If You have mythical 'errors' You may ask / analyse error mesage.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape **each** backslash like that: `String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Jonathan Lee\\eclipse-workspace\\myfile.text"`